# Why is Django not taking the integer in the DB and displaying it in the HTML template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, jinja2

I have the following basic code, which is meant to get number X, add a simple value "+1" just as proof of concept, then save that number back into the database.
Also, I require a Django based, jinja template to pull that number and render it onto a website.

My question is, why is the number failing to show up? I only get a blank space where the number is supposed to be rendered and if I remove the [:1] filter, the div is generated 3x; this tells me that the issue might be somewhere in that line but I am at a loss. The code is:

## /views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.template import Context, loader
    from home.models import DeathNum

    def index(request):
        counter = DeathNum.objects.get(pk=1)
        fj = counter.deaths
        t = loader.get_template('home/basenum.html')
        c = {'number_post': str(fj)[:1]}
        return HttpResponse(t.render(c))


    def increment(request):
        counter1 = DeathNum.objects.get(pk=1)
        counter1.deaths += 1
        counter1.save()
        t = loader.get_template('home/basenum.html')
        c = {'number_post': str(counter1)[:1]}
        return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

## /models.py:

```
 from django.db import models

 class DeathNum(models.Model):

     deaths = models.IntegerField()


     def __str__(self):
         return "{0}/{1}\n".format(self.id, self.deaths)
```

## /basenum.html:

```
      {% extends "home/index.html" %}
      {% block content %}
         <br />
          <div class="banner">
           <div class="bannerNum">
            <p div class="numberOf">
             Number of deaths in Blank since 1999:
        </p>
                {% for post in number_post %}
          <br /><br /><br />
          <p class="death1">
            {{ post.deaths }}
          </p>
                {% endfor %}
         </div>
        </div> 
        {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to your question.**

`number_post` is *string*. Why for loop to display the `str` ? Please remove the for loop from your template and just add this...

```
{{ number_post }}
```

Or

**Another solution to your question**

I believe you want to show all the deaths. Please consider below approach?

```
death_nums = DeathNum.objects.all()
return render(request, 'deaths.html', {'death_nums': death_nums})
```

And in HTML

```
{% for death_num in death_nums %}
    {{ death_num.deaths }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand. You asked me why I'm using a for loop and then in the HTML you introduce another for loop? Perhaps I have more than one for loop and I didn't notice. Can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: @Guren Sorry I've edited my answer now.  let me know if something not understand

Comment: Your answer helped me out a lot! Especially the idea to remove the for_loop.